# Help Ubuntu and Windows won't shutdown

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, dell, shutdown

I've decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 along with Windows 10 on my Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Series. Now both OS's can't shut down properly.

What is looks like is that all processes are killed during the process but it never powers off completely unless I long press the power button. Then Ubuntu splash screen freezes at some point and on Windows the screen goes dark as if it had worked but since I can only turn on the laptop again after long pressing, it has the same problem.

After doing some search, a few solutions involved changing the definition of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT on /etc/default/grub. However, none of that worked for me.

sudo shutdown -h now didn't do it either.

This is what seems to go on during the shut down:
[image]

Booting seems alright (can't be sure) - though when I choose to initialize Windows there is this weird purple screen between the setup option screen and the Windows loading screen. (but sorry that's not really the reason for this topic lol).

Lastly, I can restart okay.

Sorry about my English and long post but hopefully I can't get this solved soon as I don't think shutting down my laptop by holding down the power button is good for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Report this as a bug on launchpad.net. A few thoughts. This is mostly an annoyance. Because the system halted properly, it is safe to use the power button to finish the shutdown. I had this problem on an Acer and suspected it partly came from plymouth (the splash screen). In grub, edit out splash and quiet. But then use ctrl-alt-f1 to go to a tty. Use shutdown -P (not -h. Yes -P is default but use it anyway.) from there. Combo of no plymouth plus shutdown outside of X took care of it for me. Also, kernel upgrades my fix it over time.

Comment: you sure it is no problem pressing the power button in this case, will try some other fix attempts when I have time. thanks.

Comment: I'm sure because once halt is reached the disks have synced and you'll find some similar questions with the same statement; but... it is ultimately your system, your research, and your decision. :)

Comment: ops sorry I meant your suggestion and some other attempts. yeah, a few has had this problem apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved this by chance when I updated the drivers listed on Drivers & Downloads on [Dell Support Page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04) . There was a BIOS update there.